# Adding numbers in front of printed list items in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

So I have a list like:

```
    L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

and

```
    for x in L:
        print(x)
```

returns

```
    'a'
    'b'
    'c'
    'd'
```

but I would like to see

```
    1. 'a'
    2. 'b'
    3. 'c'
    4. 'd'
```

I would like to have this work for any size the list might grow or shrink to.
I have tried a few things but I am very new to programming and nothing has worked.

Comment: look up [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the index in Python for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
for i, x in enumerate(L):
    print('{0}. {1}'.format(i, repr(x)))
```

Comment: Using `repr` will not give the same result.  `print` uses `str`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I used `repr` because otherwise it won't include the quotes.

Comment: I see.  I'm not sure if that's what he wants, however, because his original would not include the quotation marks.  I could go either way on that.

Comment: Thank you Brendan. And thank you zondo, I just changed `repr` to `str`

Comment: Brendan, I looked on python.org at enumerate because I wanted to learn more. But it didn't answer a question I have about the way you printed it. in the beginning the `{0}. {1}` what exactly does that do?

Comment: It's part of python string formatting - https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax